# Listen to a change value that depends on another value in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node called RecentChats and another called Users. In my code, I get the RecentChats first and then, for each RecentChat, I get the remote user from Firebase. As you can see in the picture below, each User has a child called lastSeen. I would like to be able to listen to that child and change the view from the layout according to its value. In the current state, the user value is retrieved again when its respective RecentChat changes. I haven't been able to make the User listener independent from the RecentChat one.

This is the User data structure:
[image]

This is the item from the RecyclerView (as I said, I want to be able to change the color of the dot in real time according to the user status):
[image]

**RecentChatsFragment.java**

```
public class RecentChatsFragment extends Fragment {

    private final DatabaseReference recentChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(KEY_COLLECTION_RECENT_CHATS);
    private ValueEventListener incomingMessagesListener;

    private List<RecentChat> recentChatList;
    private List<User> remoteUserList;

    private RecyclerView recentChatsRV;
    private TextView errorMessageTV;
    private CardView welcomingCV;
    private ProgressBar recentChatsPB;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_chats, container, false);

        errorMessageTV = view.findViewById(R.id.errorMessageTV);
        welcomingCV = view.findViewById(R.id.welcomingCV);

        setupRV(view);
        setupFab(view);
        getRecentChats();
        return view;
    }

    private void setupRV(View view) {
        recentChatList = new ArrayList<>();
        remoteUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        recentChatsPB = view.findViewById(R.id.recentChatsPB);
        recentChatsRV = view.findViewById(R.id.recentChatsRV);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recentChatsRV.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }

    private void setupFab(View view) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.usersListFB).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), UsersListChatsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    private void getRecentChats() {
        changeViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
        incomingMessagesListener = recentChatsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    final int[] i = {0};
                    recentChatList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String[] usersID = dataSnapshot.getKey().split("-");
                        if (FIREBASE_USER.getUid().equals(usersID[0]) || FIREBASE_USER.getUid().equals(usersID[1])) {
                            RecentChat recentChat = dataSnapshot.getValue(RecentChat.class);
                            if (FIREBASE_USER.getUid().equals(usersID[0])) {
                                recentChat.setRemoteUserID(usersID[1]);
                            } else {
                                recentChat.setRemoteUserID(usersID[0]);
                            }
                            recentChatList.add(recentChat);
                        }
                        if (++i[0] == snapshot.getChildrenCount()) {
                            checkChatList();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    changeViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                errorMessageTV.setText(String.format("%s", getString(R.string.no_users_available)));
                changeViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getRemoteUser() {
        remoteUserList.clear();
        for (RecentChat recentChat : recentChatList) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
                    .child(recentChat.getRemoteUserID())
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            User remoteUser = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            remoteUser.setId(snapshot.getKey());
                            remoteUserList.add(remoteUser);
                            if (remoteUserList.size() == recentChatList.size()) {
                                recentChatsRV.setAdapter(new RecentChatsAdapter(
                                        getContext(),
                                        recentChatList,
                                        remoteUserList)
                                );
                                changeViewsVisibility(View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.GONE, View.GONE);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            errorMessageTV.setText(String.format("%s", getString(R.string.no_users_available)));
                            changeViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void checkChatList() {
        if (recentChatList.size() > 0) {
            sortListAlphab(); //Ordering by timestamp
            getRemoteUser();
        } else {
            changeViewsVisibility(View.GONE, View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void sortListAlphab() {
        Collections.sort(recentChatList, (recentChatList, rc1) -> {
            long s1 = recentChatList.getTimestamp();
            long s2 = rc1.getTimestamp();
            return Long.compare(s1, s2);
        });
    }

    private void changeViewsVisibility(int recentChatsVis, int errorMessageVis, int welcomingVis, int pbVis) {
        recentChatsRV.setVisibility(recentChatsVis);
        errorMessageTV.setVisibility(errorMessageVis);
        welcomingCV.setVisibility(welcomingVis);
        recentChatsPB.setVisibility(pbVis);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (incomingMessagesListener != null) {
            recentChatsRef.removeEventListener(incomingMessagesListener);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The problem is the way that I retrieve the data from Firebase. That's what makes listening to the changes from the User node a bit difficult. The ideal thing would be to have the RecentChats and the Users values independent from each other in order to be able to listen to their changes individually, which is a approach that I don't think it's possible due to the dependency of RecentChats to Users. I tried to change the addSingleValueEventListener to addValueEventListener on getRemoteUser(), but it didn't work. I'm looking for a workaround in which I can still listening to the RecentChats changes as well as the User changes.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added a bit more insight on the problem and what behaviour I expect.